# iOS push to PHP usage app info

Tags: php, ios

after creating an iOS app which pulls data from a PHP server using JSON.

I want to design an app which pushs data, send data related of the use of the app like:
- days the app is used
- time the app is used
- who is registered on my app when is running
- etc.

Any experience to share? Some framework?

Best!

Comment: This isn't the best site to ask this kind of question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using Google's Analytics SDK, if you are OK with them housing the data.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/

Saves you running the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write your own web service. Since you are already using PHP, here is a great tutorial to get you started.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app